# url not working in curl function

Tags: php, curl

I am using the curl function on my site if I use the url http://www.markettrendsignal.com/v1/market/header_cal.php it is showing the error not found else if I removed the www in front of the error it is working fine but I want the www in the url. How can I resolve it. I check the url it is working fine with www and without www. I am using the curl function in the same doamin.It is showing the following error.

"Not Found
The requested URL /v1/market/header_cal.php was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat) Server at www.markettrendsignal.com Port 80"

```
                 $ch = curl_init();
                 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.markettrendsignal.com/v1/market/header_cal.php');
                 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                 $contents = curl_exec ($ch);
                 print_r($contents);
                 curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: Could you post your complete cURL code?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue; both variants [give the exact same result](http://codepad.viper-7.com/9qCPh5).

Comment: @ceejayoz lol that's a really good point actually haha it's server side CURL so wtf does it matter which url is being used :P

Answer (score 0):

use CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION on curl_setopt function. It will follow the link even in redirect. This is caused because for your htacces file. Domain hosted without www and you putting the link www so the page redirected as 301. See the available option http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.markettrendsignal.com/v1/market/header_cal.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$curled=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($curled);
```

It is working well on my side, please use this

Comment: not working  $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.markettrendsignal.com/v1/market/header_cal.php');
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
      $contents = curl_exec ($ch);
      print_r($contents);
      curl_close ($ch);

Comment: There appears to be no redirect, this was my first thought as well.

Comment: How can I change the htaccess file??

Comment: Contact with your hosting provider, may be this will your server issue